# Display custom format name on django admin page

Tags: python, django

I want to display first name and last name. To achieve that, I have used `__str__()` method. But it is not working.

```
class OnlineUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}"
```

Instead it display, user ID.

In `admin.py`,

```
class OnlineUsersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # a list of displayed columns name.
    list_display=['user']

admin.site.register(OnlineUsers, OnlineUsersAdmin)
```

Where I'm doing wrong? How to get the format I want?

**Version:**

```
Django==2.0.1
```

**Debug:**

```
user_info=OnlineUsers.objects.get_or_create(user=self.user)
print(user_info.__str__())
```

**Output:**

```
((<OnlineUsers: FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME >, False))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `__str__` instead of user in list_display:

```
list_display=['__str__']
```

Otherwise you tell django to show `user` field. And since `User` model doen't have overrided `__str__` method you see user's id.

Also you can just remove `list_display` attribute. In this case `__str__` will be used by default.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`list_display`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) support ***callable methods*** too. So, define a **`user(...)`** method on Model admin as,

```
class OnlineUsersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # a list of displayed columns name.
    list_display = ['user']

    def user(self, instance):
        return instance.__str__()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, inside return you can return only str + str, not str + int. So, you have to convert every int to str

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Fabonacci(models.Model):
    numstr = models.IntegerField()
    terms = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return "The first " + str(self.numstr) + " terms in fibonacci series : " + self.terms
```